# Is lending a physical PS or Xbox disc protected under the first-sale doctrine?

Tags: copyright, copyright-transfer

If I wanted to share or sell my used games (original disc) is it legal?

Answer (score -1):

You can sell it, yes. Plenty of stores sell used video games.

Comment: how about lending?

Comment: Most console games let you do it, but obviously PC games will make you install them and register and all that so they aren't meant for that. It's not really a big deal with console games unless you were charging to borrow them or something like that. Obviously they know people borrow games.